# Mouse wheel clicks but doesn't scroll after 22.04 LTS inline upgrade

Tags: mouse, scrolling

Old Asus laptop that was running Xubuntu 20.04 LTS, upgraded in place to 22.04 LTS. Mouse is a Logitech M320 USB wireless. The middle button clicks, pastes, etc., but does not scroll (anywhere, any app). Everything else seems OK.

I installed imwheel but haven't really made sense of how it works. My xinput output is below. Any ideas where I can look?

Thanks.

```
~ $ xinput list-props 11
Device 'Logitech M280/320/275':
    Device Enabled (150):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (152): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (286):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (287):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (288):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (289):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (290):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (291): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (292): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Lock Enabled (293):    0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Lock Enabled Default (294):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (295):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (296):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (297): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (298): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (299):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (300):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (301):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (302): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (303): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (271): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (272):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (273):    0, 0
    Device Node (274):  "/dev/input/event6"
    Device Product ID (275):    1133, 16448
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (304):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (305):   1
    libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance (306):    15
    libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance Default (307):    15
    libinput High Resolution Wheel Scroll Enabled (308):    1
```

**UPDATE --**
It was the mouse itself after all. The timing was perfect: It scrolled right before the upgrade, but not right after. However, it won't scroll on any computer and another mouse works fine here. So it's the hardware.

I just love (*NOT!*) when the timing is perfect... Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the output of `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse`

Comment: @Raffa It sounds like you might have an answer for my question here: https://askubuntu.com/q/1454673/48214 I'll be curious to hear what you think. Thanks!

Comment: @Raffa `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse accel-profile 'default'
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse double-click 400
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse drag-threshold 8
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse left-handed false
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse middle-click-emulation false
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse natural-scroll false
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse speed 1.0`

Answer (score -1):

This could arise from several things.

1. Drivers: make sure drivers are installed and updated. Try purging the old drivers and installing new.
2. Kernal version doesn't support the drivers installed. Try updating kernal version. Usually **apt get update**

You're particular device may not be compatible with the version you have upgraded to quite yet also. So you may have to wait for support.

I don't think Logitec actually supports Linux OS. There is just a universal driver that sometimes works with the device. Checkout UVC to learn more

Comment: Maybe you have an answer for this one?  https://askubuntu.com/q/1454673/48214 Thanks!