# What can be the cause of USB HUB disconnecting after suspend?

Tags: usb, suspend

I have a Dell laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 and I have a USB HUB attached with 3 devices: keyboard, wireless mouse and a headset. Everything works perfectly until I leave the laptop for a while and it enters suspend mode. After waking up, the system does not recognize the HUB nor any device in it. The HUB doesn't show up with `lsusb` as if it was not reinitialized after sleep mode. If I unplug the HUB and plug it back, it's working again.

I assume it is some energy-saving issue. I've already replaced the HUB to rule out that it's the HUB that's faulty and also replaced the mouse (it had issues with scrolling, probably unrelated).

The devices and the HUB works perfectly on another laptop with Win11.

What config options should I check? What can be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Related: [Ubuntu 22.04.1: How to automatically reset USB connections upon wake?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1454673)